# Merge Existing Partition in HIVE

Tags: hive, partitioning

How to merge existing Partitions and make it to one Partition.
For ex : I have Partitions on Year column like year=2011,year=2012,year=2013,year=2014.

My requirement is to merge partitions from 2011 to 2013 partitions.
So that I can have only 2 partitions 2013 and 2014.

Please help.

Regards,
Manoj

Answer (score 1):

1) create new target table

2) Insert data into target table with dynamic partition loading:

```
insert overwrite table partition (partition_year)
select col1, col2 ..., case when year between 2011 and 2013 then 2013
                            when year >=2014 then 2014 
                         end  as partition_year from source_table
```

3) drop source_table

Answer (score 1):

If your partitioning column `year` is defined as STRING, then you can just...

1. create a new partition for `year=History` *(for instance)*
2. move **brutally** the data files from directories such as `.../year=2011/` to the new dir `.../year=History/`
3. drop the partitions that are now empty